# Error when Saving JSON Obj in MarkLogic using Spring data abstraction for MarkLogic

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, spring-data, marklogic

I am receiving a JSON from a producer application and when I try to convert that into a JSON Object and save it into MarkLogic as `.json`. I donot have the POJO for the incoming unknown data to have a field to annotate it with @Id. I am getting below Error

```
@Autowired
MarkLogicOperations ops;

    @StreamListener(MultiInputSink.INPUT)
        public synchronized void handle(String ConsumerContents) {    


            JSONObject jsobObj = new JSONObject(consumerContents);

            ops.write(jsobObj, "Consumer");

            logger.info("Consumer Data "+jsobObj.toString());


        }
```

Below is the error:-

```
nested exception is java.lang.illegalArgumentException: your entity of type org.json.JSONObject does not have a method or field annotated with field org.springframework.data.annotated.id
```

I need to save JSONs as it comes. Is there a way to go around this ? Thank you.

Note:- I am using this for Spring-data-abstraction for MarkLogic https://github.com/malteseduck/spring-data-marklogic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common problem with new marklogic developers is using a high level interface when a 'low' level one is more appropriate.
In this case the spring API exposes operations based on spring entities -- which would work ok if you had spring entities to begin with, but you don't.  You have 'plain json' -- aka 'text'.  In which case you do NOT want to convert those to entities just to store them in MarkLogic -- try single-stepping sometime though one of the high level APIs -- The amount of work involved to translate from string JSON to Entity then back to string to send to ML is mindboggeling. Not just wrt performance but also data fidelity.  Java to JSON is not 1:1 lossless or unambiguous.  If you *start out* with an Entity then the API makes some sense, but you dont want to convert your real JSON into an entity just to write it back out.

Instead look for one of the other APIs.  For example executeWithClient  will give you access to the next 'lower' API. 
From there you can write out JSON as JSON (text) with less fuss.
With the DatabaseClient interface you still have to choose amoung a range of abstractions -- all of which still require you to tranform your perfectly good JSON text into an object of some form so the API can transform it back to text.

For the DocumentManager (part of DatabaseClient) you need a WriteHandle -- the StringWriteHandle *should work* for this.

A more direct (and effecient) method is to execute the document insert via an xquery exec.   This project has some examples:

> https://github.com/DALDEI/mlperf

One example:  (kotlin source)

```
val repo = client.newServerEval()
repo.addVariable("url", getURI("evalstring", id))
repo.addVariable("content", (str))
repo.xquery(
    "declare variable  \$url as xs:string external ;"+
          "declare variable ${'$'}content external ;"+
          "xdmp:document-insert( \$url , xdmp:unquote( \$content ) )"
)

repo.eval().forEach {
  println(it.string)
}
```

If performance is important for this app, I recommend experimenting with different approaches.  Performance can vary dramatically (by 100x or more) with seemingly minor differences in choice of API and methodology.  The above example is from a small program that exercises different APIs writing out large numbers of small JSON files.   Performance can vary from 5 docs/sec to 2000 docs/sec with roughly the same amount of code.